# how to output a grid of ovals from a 2d array

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops, nested

I am trying to output a grid off ovals in a 4x4 grid, i want the ovals to be coloured depending on the number in the array and I want the ovals to be in the correct grid position. However when i run my project it only outputs the first one in the top left corner?

```
public class boardView extends View {

public int IslandX;
public int IslandY;

private Canvas canvas;

public boardView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
int gameBoard[][] = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 2}};
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

public void DrawBoard(Canvas canvas){
    Paint Island = new Paint();
    Island.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int R = 0; R < 4; R++) {
            IslandX=i*500;
            IslandY=R*500;
            switch (gameBoard[i][R]){
                case 0:
                    Island.setColor(Color.BLUE);

                    canvas.drawOval(IslandX, IslandY, 50, 50, Island);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Island.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    canvas.drawOval(IslandX, IslandY, 50, 50, Island);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Island.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    canvas.drawOval(IslandX, IslandY, 50, 50, Island);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Island.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    canvas.drawOval(IslandX, IslandY, 50, 50, Island);
            }
        }

    }

}}
```

Comment: Side note: since you're unconditionally executing `canvas.drawRect(IslandX, IslandY, 50, 50, Island);` it makes sense to remove it from the switch statement

Comment: I don't know what's the issue, but I can point you to two things: first, `drawOval` accepts floats as parameters not ints, and second, you pass the same "right" and "bottom" coordinates in all calls. Further, try to multiply it with something smaller than `500` - maybe it "draws" it out of screen ?

Comment: sorry i changed it to drawRect to test if that was the same, i have tried loads of numbers from low to high, but on all different ones it just outputs one oval in the top left and that its?